# How do I model a table tennis match in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, rails-models

I am attempting to model a table tennis match in rails.  Here is what I have:

Game Model:
team_1_score
team_2_score
team_1_id
team_2_id

Team Model:
game_id
player_id

Player Model:
Name

So each game will consist of 2 teams (of either 1 or 2 players each).
Then I was planning on linking game to player with has_many, :through.  I don't think this will work because of the 2 instances of team in each game.  But I really don't know where I should go from here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For a `Game`, how do you decide which is `team_1` and which is `team_2`? Do you have something line `home_team` and `away_team` or any other distinguishing feature?

Comment: Team 1 and team 2 are arbitrary and only act as a way to group players for a match.  These teams can change regularly and often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do the has_many :through between players and games, but it might be easier if you start out with something like this:

```
Team Model
id
name
has_many :players
has_many :games

Player Model
id
name
team_id 
has_one :team
```

Then the Games model would have something like (in addition to what you already have):

```
has_one :team1, :class_name => 'Team'
has_one :team2, :class_name => 'Team'
```

Comment: I don't want a player to be assigned a team but I do want a team to be composed of players.  I essentially want to be able to create a team from the players.  But I will work with what you gave me and see if I can figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Well, you could introduce another table called "team_players", which just has foreign keys tying the players to the teams.  This would give you the flexibility of assigning players to more than 1 team.  (Sorry, I can't seem to format this right)

TeamPlayer model:
team_id
player_id
belongs_to :team
belongs_to :player

Player model
has_many :teams, :through => :team_players

Team Model
has_many :players, :through => :team_players

Comment: Thanks, I think I can figure it out now.